# CMFCColorDialog not working in MFC Property Page as Release, OK as Debug

Tags: debugging, mfc, release, mfc-feature-pack

The title pretty much explains it. Here's the function to display the ColorDialog when a button is clicked:

```
void 
CMyPP::OnBnClickedButtonCol()
{
    CMFCColorDialog dlg(m_text_colour);

    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) 
    { 
        m_text_colour = dlg.GetColor(); 
    }
}
```

In the release build nothing happens when the button is clicked. I can't see any difference in the VS 2008 options between debug and release to explain it. I think CMFCColorDialog is from the MFC feature pack but the rest of the program is basic MFC - could that explain it?
Thanks

Comment: Step into the MFC code, this may give you a clue.

Comment: be more specific about the "nothing happens" please, and also be specific about which button you are talking about, and add some pictures too of the "working" debug version... so any info will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I missed out a crucial piece of information, in that the Debug version was using mfc in a shared dll while the release was static. Then I found this solution which has worked for me: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7245ee72-ffd5-4167-b690-c2edc10fb88e/static-link-fails-with-vs2008-mfc-feature-pack .
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the linked solution here (links might become invalid over time). And please accept your answer.

Comment: OK this is what I had to do. Quote from link above:
In your resource includes (choose: Edit->Resource Includes while in the resource editor) add in the second section: 
    #if !defined(_AFXDLL)
    #include "afxribbon.rc"  // MFC ribbon and control bar resources
    #endif